# Pig: Count Frequency of distinct Tuples in a file

Tags: json, count, apache-pig

I have a file that has json entries that look like:

```
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "fighter", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "virtua"}
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "case", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "martin"}
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "fighter", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "virtua"}
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "fighter", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "virtua"}
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "case", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "martin"}
```

I want to calculate the frequency of the distinct json objects in the file. I saw other answers where we use Group By and count() functions in Pig. I am not sure if I am using them right but I am not getting the required results. My output should look like:

```
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "fighter", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "virtua", "count": "3"}
{"child_pos": "NN", "parent_pos": "NN", "parent": "case", "child_dep": "nn", "parent_dep": "nsubj", "child": "martin", "count": "2"}
```

The order is not really important. Can someone plesae give me some pointers?

Comment: please share what you have tried and why do you think this is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that can be used, with condition of all fields to be groupded If you want in other format you can read feild from tuple and use any other format

```
A = LOAD '/user/root/test12.json' USING JsonLoader('child_pos:chararray,               parent_pos:chararray, parent:chararray, child_dep:chararray, parent_dep:chararray, child:chararray');
B = GROUp A by (child_pos, parent_pos, parent, child_dep, parent_dep, child) ;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, COUNT(A.child_pos) as COUNTX;
STORE C into 'user/data/json_out.json' USING JsonStorage();

out put is ... 
{"group":    {"child_pos":"NN","parent_pos":"NN","parent":"case","child_dep":"nn","parent_dep":"nsubj","child":"martin"},"COUNTX":2}
{"group":{"child_pos":"NN","parent_pos":"NN","parent":"fighter","child_dep":"nn","parent_dep":"nsubj","child":"virtua"},"COUNTX":3}
```